# Javascript Filter an array based on multiple conditions using native functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a situation where I need to filter an array of objects based on certain conditions. And here what it is

- There is an error response and the response is an array of objects. Each object has nodes `message`, `type`, `keyValues`
- `keyValues` is an array and may have 3 different items at-most. The nodes for each element are  `key` & `value`
- `key` can have one of the following 3 values `by-date` , `by-unique-object`, `by-related-object`
- value for `by-date` will have the value as date object
- value for `by-unique-object`, `by-related-object` will have object as

```
    value: {
       uri: "object-uri-1"
    }
```

- The `uri` has specific pattern and same for both of the types `by-unique-object`, `by-related-object`.

So, from the given error array I need to filter only the records which got only `by-date` and should not have other 2 types with those types of URI pattern

Here what I did -

```
let errors = [
    {
        message: "Error message 1",
        type: "error",
        keyValues: [
            {
                key: "by-date",
                value: {
                    date: {year:2020, month: 4, day: 6}
                }
            },
            {
                key: "by-unique-object",
                value: {
                    uri: "object-uri-1"
                }
            },
            {
                key: "by-related-object",
                value: {
                    uri: "object-uri-1"
                }
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        message: "Error message 2",
        type: "error",
        keyValues: [
            {
                key: "by-date",
                value: {
                    date: {year:2020, month: 4, day: 5}
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        message: "Error message 3",
        type: "error",
        keyValues: [
            {
                key: "by-date",
                value: {
                    date: {year:2020, month: 4, day: 6}
                }
            },
            {
                key: "by-unique-object",
                value: {
                    uri: "object-uri-3"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        message: "Error message 4",
        type: "warning",
        keyValues: [
            {
                key: "by-unique-object",
                value: {
                    uri: "object-uri-4"
                }
            },
            {
                key: "by-related-object",
                value: {
                    uri: "object-uri-4"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        message: "Error message 5",
        type: "warning",
        keyValues: [
            {
                key: "by-date",
                value: {
                    date: {year:2020, month: 4, day: 8}
                }
            },
            {
                key: "by-related-object",
                value: {
                    uri: "object-uri-4"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        message: "Error message 6",
        type: "warning",
        keyValues: [
            {
                key: "by-date",
                value: {
                    date: {year:2020, month: 4, day: 9}
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];
const matchObjectUriPattern = (uri) => /object-uri-.*/g.test(uri);
const hasByDate = (item) => item.key === "by-date" && item.value && item.value.date;
const hasUniqueObject = (item) => item.key === "by-unique-object" && matchObjectUriPattern(item.value.uri);
const hasRelatedObject = (item) => item.key === "by-related-object" && matchObjectUriPattern(item.value.uri);


const checkOnlyByDate = (error) => {
    let keyValues = error && error.keyValues ? error.keyValues : [];
    let byDate = keyValues.find(hasByDate);
    let byUniqueObject = keyValues.find(hasUniqueObject);
    let byRelatedObject = keyValues.find(hasRelatedObject);

    return byDate && (!byUniqueObject && !byRelatedObject);
};

const filteredErrors = errors.filter(checkOnlyByDate);

console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredErrors));
```

What I did works well, but is there a better way to do it ? Or some better way to handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your solution! Based on your requirements I came up with:

```
const filteredErrors = errors.filter(({keyValues}) => 
  keyValues.every(({key}) => key === "by-date"))
```

Which only returns those error messages whose `keyValues` array only contains objects with `key` === "by-date"

I can't say this is better or worse than what you provided because I'm not sure how else you might be using this code. But I wanted to add my own interpretation of the problem.

Comment: Interesting I completely missed that Array.prototype.every() is meant to do such job !! I ended up having so much of code. This is what I wanted less code but super effective.  Thanks and stay safe in this difficult covid19 situation !!